# Recursion: Factorial

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Factorial {

    int fact (int n) {

        int result; 

        if (n==1 ||n==0) 
            return 1;

        else 
            result = n*fact(n-1);
        return result;
    }
```

Assuming n is less than 0 (-1, -2, etc) and the factorial value of these values are "Not valid" (I want the system to print out "Not valid" if the input value (n) is less than 0. How do I modify the code. I understand the method only returns a integer value and not String.

Comment: either check it before you call your method or throw an exception

Comment: throw `IllegalArgumentException` with message `no should not be less than 0`

Comment: @Saravana of course, thats the best solution, but I think that it is a little bit early for the OP to deal with exceptions, if he doesn't even know anything about System.out.println()

Answer (score 2):

As @Saravana said, you must add a throws statement that looks something like this:

```
    int factorial (int n) 
    {
        if (n < 0) 
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry value cannot be negative");
        }

        if (n==1 || n==0) 
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return n * fact(n-1);
        }
    }
```

If any value less than zero there will be an error saying that the user did not enter the value correct. Hope this helped! :)

Comment: I got this when I try to run the programme!

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sorry
 at exams.Factorial.fact(Factorial.java:10)
 at exams.Recursion.main(Recursion.java:7)

Comment: That is what you want the compiler to do. You want to let the user know that what they entered was incorrect and it should throw the exception that they caused.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `if` statement checking for negative input.  A factorial should never return negative, so you can return `-1` to indicate an error:

```
int fact (int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (n==1 || n==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n * fact(n-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want the system to print out "Not valid" if the input value (n) is less than 0

You can do this by adding

```
if (n < 0) {
    System.out.println("Not valid");
}
```

at the beginning of the method. The String "Not valid" will not be returned by the method, but it will be printed out. 
After that it would be meaningful to exit the method without further calculation. You can do this according to your needs in either of following ways:

If your programm can do more then just calculating a factorial and you need in any case a return value:

```
 if (n < 0) {
     System.out.println("Not valid");
     return -1; // or some other inapplicable for a factorial result integer value
 }
```

or you could also just "hard exit" the whole programm whitout returning any value like

```
if (n < 0) {
     System.out.println("Not valid");
     System.exit(1); // 1 or any other nonzero integer value 
                     // to tell the system it exits with an error. 0 otherwise
 }
```